# Powerquery merge multiple pairs of columns without hard coding column names

Tags: list, merge, powerquery

I wonder if anyone can help me? I’m making a work rota for team members. I have a table of their planned leave and a table of their work patterns (where N denotes a non-working day). I want to merge these into one table showing presence or absence.

So far I have joined the two tables on date to create query Merge1 in which each staff member has two columns: a column of leave (column names are initials) and a column with their work patterns with columns names like: Patterns.initials.

[image]

I have made a list of pairs of columns for each staff member called List_of_Pairs of the form:
{{MMK, Patterns.MMK}, {KM, Patterns.KM}, {KN, Patterns.KN}} and so on.

As you can see in the screenshot I’ve used my List_of_Pairs to reorder my Merge1 table.
But now I want to use it to merge each pair of columns to get one column per staff member.
As staff members change over time, it needs to be dynamic to continue working without intervention.

I know how to use Table.CombineColumns to merge two columns eg
= Table.CombineColumns(Custom1,{"MMK", "Patterns.MMK"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.None),"MMK.1")

But how do I do them all at once? I guess I can substitute List_of_Pairs between the first {}, but how do I give each new column a meaningful name that will contain the initials of the staff member? What can I put instead of “MMK.1” to make that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In powerquery, you can use this to merge all the XX and Patterns.XX columns

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
x=List.Alternate(Table.ColumnNames(Source),1,1,0), //or pump in your own set of base column titles here
w= List.Transform(x, each 
    let b=Table.FromColumns({Table.Column(Source,_)}&{Table.Column(Source,"Patterns."&_)})
    in Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(b, {{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}, "en-US"),{"Column1", "Column2"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("", QuoteStyle.None),"data")[data]),
v = Table.FromColumns({Source[Date]}&w,{"Date"}&x),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(v,{{"Date", type date}})
in #"Changed Type"
```

[image]

Overall: Take the alternate column names. For each of those [ pull two columns, the name and the name with Patterns in front of it. Convert those two columns/lists into a table. Merge the two columns in the table to a third column. Disregard everything except the merged column. ] Now you have a list where each item in the list is the merged column from their related column names. In the Table.FromColumns step, convert those columns back into a final table after appending the original date column

Comment: Thanks very much for your time on this, it's much appreciated. Can you say something about how step w is intended to work? I haven't got it going but that is no doubt my inexperience!

Comment: Ah step W!  For each base column name [MMK,KM,KN] using List.Transform(), transform it as follows:  pull the (namehere) column with Table.Column(), pull the Patterns prefixed (namehere) column with with Table.Column(). Now you have two columns.  Use Table.FromColumns() to convert those two lists into a two-column table and Table.CombineColumns() to merge those into a three column table. Now just keep the new column by ending the row with [data]. So overall, grab two columns, convert those to a table, merge them, then just grab the new column.  And do that for each item [MMK, etc]

Comment: Blimey! I have now got it going and it's like magic! Thanks so much :-)